# vue + deno + vscode => How to integrate them for comfort development?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vite, deno

#### How correctly configure vscode for vue project using deno?

---

*Important spoiler - problems are related only to **highlighting in vscode**, because builds, dev, scripts... all these stuff is worked!*

---

[Deno + Vue](https://docs.deno.com/runtime/tutorials/how_to_with_npm/vue) is very attractive option! You can write api and ui aka in monorepository and share for example models, types or validators among them... etc.

#### My problem exploring notes:

1. as I already mentioned early - only highlighting in vscode is the target of this article
2. I think that *.vue files in vscode are supported with volar extension, so it expect typescript lsp, not deno's one - and this is main problem
3. so if we use deno's lsp it don't understand SingleFileComponent syntax

I try to make independent configurations both for typescript and deno, sync their aliases, imports, node_modules etc.
It works!
But it is not pretty enough and I hope more powerful and standard solutions are exists.

Answer (score 0):

**my standard part of solution:**

- `vite.config.mts` with all `npm:*` imports
- `deno.json` with aliases in `imports` to be more closely to original npm names

---

**and additionaly strange part**:

- `.vscode/settings.json` enable deno only for api
- `tsconfig.json` types if this project was standard vue-vite-node-vscode...
- also create `dev-hack` folder with `package.json` and import all modules with `npm`
- and add to `tsconfig.json` (`compilerOptions.typeRoots[`) path to `dev-hack/node_modules`

---

*So except api (if such exists) all files are served in vscode by typescript using tsconfig.json that use dev-hack/node_modules (of course node_modules in .gitignore)... And this is only for highlighting!*

*The real build/serve/dev... are worked as expected without typescript configured as explained above but only with deno+vite as written in docs.*